# How to deal with column names containing special characters like (,),$,% and spaces while querying in Hive View

Tags: view, hive, hiveql

Hope you all know that from Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character (see HIVE-6013). Any column name that is specified within backticks (`) is treated literally but it seems it is applicable to tables. In my case I have a view created using several columns which contains special characters like (,),$,% and spaces in their column names. I have used backtics while creation of view and it is created but at the time of retrieving using 'select * from view_name' I am getting below error without launching any map reduce job :

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

It generates only query id, but no job gets created, hence no logs are found. but when i tried in Hue Hive editor I got the job running but unable to fetch results.

```
counters:
File Bytes Read 1882965
File Bytes Written  2120145
Hdfs Bytes Read 43923
Hdfs Bytes Written  9250984
Hdfs Read Ops   3
Hdfs Write Ops  2

Committed Heap Bytes    220725248
Cpu Milliseconds    6420
Gc Time Millis  46
Merged Map Outputs  1
Physical Memory Bytes   286355456
Reduce Input Groups 19332
Reduce Input Records    19332
Reduce Output Records   0
Reduce Shuffle Bytes    1882961
Shuffled Maps   1
Spilled Records 19332
Virtual Memory Bytes    1629929472
Created Files   1
Records Out 0   19332
```

Is it related to permission issues?

Comment: That's not very informative -- Hive "return code 1" just means *"dude, the YARN job failed unexpectedly, go get the YARN logs to know why"*.

Comment: Ah, actually it looks like a LOCAL task, so the logs might be somewhere in your local `/tmp/hive/...`

Comment: Sorry to bother u guys , that was due to a permission issue, resolved now..

Answer (score 0):

```
select  REGEXP_REPLACE(c1, "%|)|,|-|\\$",'')) c1,
from tablename;
```

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE` above will replace all characters in " " with '' from column : c1